# How to handle pop-up in webbrowser control c#

Tags: c#, popup, controls, webbrowser-control

I use webbrowser control to navigate to a site where is a button and when the button is pressed a pop-up appear and i must make some actions in this pop-up then i must close it and return to the browser.
I tried to make this with NewWindow event, but I could not make it work

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement html in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
{
    if (html.InnerText == "Like")
    {        
        html.InvokeMember("click"); // here i press the button and the pop-up appear
       // Here I must make some actions in the pop-up(I must press other button)
       // and here I must close the popup and to continue in the first page
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code and explain *how* it does not work.

Comment: I posted my code now.

Comment: Depending of Javascript, calling a Javascript function of the html page may provide an alternative. Use webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("TheJavaScriptFunction, new object [] { ..., ... }). More complicated: to mimic the pop-up or  update Javascript variables, you may inject code with "eval".

Comment: I am facing the similar issue. Did you find any solution ?